# Is this even ubuntu grub menu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, menu

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 10 (both in different storage devices).

However I'm having this black screen since I have this Nvidia GTX 1650 SUPER, but I'm unable to configurate the nomodeset.

Each time I try to get to the grub menu, it brings me to this menu (that I'm not sure if this is the grub menu, since I found no image in the internet that looks like this one)

[image]

And there is also a code you can edit if you see where it says boot options, but also by pressing G6 you can see this.

[image]

The other problem is that when I'm in this menu, I can barely move between options or edit because when I press a key it do it like 5 times, and idk what to do to fix this.

Thanks for clearing my doubts about the CD/DVD/USB boot menu.

However, my real problem is with booting Ubuntu from the HDD.

This is everything I get each time:

[image]

UPDATE: I was able to boot from my HDD after using the repair boot with a Live USB Ubuntu.

For more information: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/install-boot-repair-ppa-fix-boot-problems/

Comment: That is a bootloader, but that is not the GRuB that gets installed to the drive.  That is the bootloader to the LiveCD/DVD/USB.  To get to the grub on the hard drive try holding down the left shift key or the F1 key at startup.  I have also seen that if you interrupt the boot by holding in the power key and powering off the host right after it starts to boot the OS that might kick off the grub menu for the next boot.

Comment: I'm sorry.. my previous comment was thinking you were trying to install. The first thing you need to do is remove your installation CD/USB from your computer... Are you able to boot into Ubuntu at all??? meaning when you get to that black screen, if you CTRL+ALT+F3, do you get a black screen with text login? if so, we can help you set the grub screen to permanently show by editing your /etc/default/grub file...

Comment: How can I edit that file if I can't even get ubuntu tu run?

Comment: I cant tell if your update is before or after your last comment.... Are you good now or can you still not boot into the OS?

Comment: I'm good now, I was able to boot it after my last Update, thanks for being so attent!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you booted to the USB. See if Ubuntu is at the top of your boot options. If it is, your boot loader must be broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is the live usb/cd menu. If you have "tried ubuntu" and kliked it just click on install ubuntu.
Caveat : if windows is installed you might need to release some disk space first to allow ubuntu to install. UNLESS you go vanilla and wipe all discs and go ubuntu only.

You'll never look back...